# Why we should Override hashcode() when overriding equals() method?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Why we should always override `hashCode()` method whenever we override `equals()` method? As per my understanding they both seem to fulfill different purpose. `hashCode()` method is used in hashtables to determine the equality of  keys. However `equals()` method is used to determine the equality of two objects.

Comment: Both your statements are somewhat wrong. This question has been asked hundreds of times before; you will get more information using google.

Comment: Just because 2 values hash to the same value doesn't mean they're equal, you need to check whether they're equal as well.

Comment: You don't need to override both, but it's actually quite easy to do since modern IDEs support code generation for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two objects are equal according to the `equals` method, their hashcodes must be equal as well. Otherwise, lookup in the hash table would fail.